# Is it posible to run an start an app (in background) automatically at a given time?

Tags: ios, notifications, background-process

I have an app that has different downloaded content each day, but I want to automatically update this content each time its available and send a notification to the user when the app has already downloaded the content locally (running in background). Should I use the applicationDidEnterBackground?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{}
```

but I was reading this background state may only last minutes and is must likely to enter background after the user changed to another app or clicked home, so how can I trigger this background state (when inactive) at 1:00 am for example? ... Another alternative could be just sending a notification to the user when new content is available and download it as soon as the user opens the app (but this is certainly plan B).
I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a silent push notification. This works the same was as a normal push notification only that it doesn't make a sound or alert the user to the fact that they have received it. Your app will then be opened in the background by iOS and will run your code.

The push will then trigger this del method:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

You can then execute your code in the completion handler. There is a time limit and the silent push notifications are throttled by APNS automatically to prevent constant spamming.

The next time the user opens your app the new content will be preloaded and waiting for them. This seems to be what you are after ... ?

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4

Near the bottom there are two parts:

"Fetching Small Amounts of Content Regularly"

and

"Using Push Notifications to Initiate a Download"

Comment: very usefull thank you, but this is only for IOS7 an later right? I need something for IOS 5.0 and later :S... is there any other option?

Comment: actually I just found https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NewsstandKit_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010838 ... forgot to mention my app is a newsstand

Comment: I just found out that the app Im working on (was passed on to me for an update) doesn't use the Newstand Framework so either I find another solution or I'll have to change everything... help please

Comment: iOS 5.0 and later ? Why? Since 72% of users are on iOS 7 and ~ 24% are on 6. iOS 5 really shouldn't be a concern ..

If you insist then I'm not sure what you can do, as like you say these API's were introduced in iOS 7.0.

Alternatively you could develop these and just list this as a feature for iOS7 users and anyone using anything earlier will just have to update when they open the app ?